# React.js How to find ref element in inner component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to share data with < Filtering /> component from onChange event to parent component < ViewTwoComponent /> I don't know how to do it

Do you know maybe how to share data between  component and his parent

ViewTwoComponent they don't see ref value and i don't know why?

On console is error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDOMNode' of undefined*

```
var ViewTwoComponent = React.createClass({
    "getInitialState": function() {
        return {
            "userTextValue": "hello11111111111111",
            "userTextRef": "userTextRef"
        }
    },
    "updateState": function(value) {
        this.setState({userTextValue: value })
    },
    "handleChange": function() {
        this.updateState(this.refs.userTextRef.getDOMNode().value)
    },
    "render": function() {
        return <div>
            <Inner />
            <Filtering refName={this.state.userTextRef} handleChange={this.handleChange} userTextValue={this.state.userTextValue} />
        </div>;
    }
})

var Inner = React.createClass({
    "render": function() {
        return <span>INNER</span>;
    }
});

var Filtering = React.createClass({
    "render": function() {
        return <span>
            <input type="text" ref={this.props.refName} onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.userTextValue} />
        </span>;
    }
});

React.render(< ViewTwoComponent />, document.getElementById("inner"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing what you mean when you try to reference `this.refs.userTextRef` but I'm assuming you want the value that's in your state. I'm also going to assume that the value of the key `userTextRef` is not actually `userTextRef`. You could try accessing the value by using square brackets.

```
  "handleChange": function() {
    this.updateState(this.refs[userTextRef]getDOMNode().value)
  }
```

Comment: i want to share data with <Filtering /> component from onChange event to parent component <ViewTwoComponent  /> I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to React, but from what I remember of the tutorials, you should be passing a function of the `Filtering` component to the `ViewTwoComponent`.

```
var Filtering = React.createClass({
        "childChanged" : function(child, value) {
           console.log("child: " + child + "change value to: " value);
        },
        "render": function() {
            return <span>
                <input type="text" ref={this.props.refName} onChange={this.props.handleChange} value={this.props.userTextValue} notifyParent={this.childChanged} />
            </span>;
        }
    });
```

And then, in the `handleChange` method of the `ViewTwoComponent` class, you call `this.props.notifyParent(this, this.state.userTextValue);`